# Angulars JS with the filter & ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

First please apologize myself if I make any typing error (I am french).

Well, I am trainning on Angular JS and I would like to use the filter on one specific field but my problem is that the filter is based on many fieds.

here is my filter:

```
<div class=main_frame ng-repeat="x in artiste | filter: recherche_artiste">
<h2>x.name </h2><img ng-src={{x.picture}} />
</div>
```

My problem is that I would like that the filter impact only the artist name and not all the fields of my array "artiste".

in my app.JS, $scope.artiste is an array[100] who contains objects like:
Array[100]
0
:
Object
$$hashKey
:
"object:14"
_id
:
"57252e30bbcf354d21c5fc19"
age
:
38
name
:
"Mccarty Buckner"
picture
:
"http://lorempixel.com/800/500"
**proto**
:
Object
1
:
Object
$$hashKey
:
"object:15"
_id
:
"57252e304cf25e47b014303e"
age
:
39
name
:
"Nguyen Kane"
picture
:
"http://lorempixel.com/600/400"
**proto**
:
Object

The problem is when I hit on filter "HTTP" or simply "p" for example, the filter doesn"t work because as you can see above, http is contained in all the the picture field.
Otherwise, the filter works good if I hit "y" for example as there is no "y" in the "picture" fields neither in the _id field.

**So my question is, is there any solution to apply my filter only on the "name" field, but keeping the corresponding "picture" field dynamically?**

Thanks in advance for your help.

I precise, I am using slowly angular only since a short time ago so I am not an expert:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-repeat="x in artiste | filter: {name : recherche_artiste}"
```

Comment: I try it and I keep you posted;:)